# On hovering change colors of the triangle

Tags: html, css, css-animations

I want to create a simple keyframe animation. I have created a triangle. Triangle color changes when you hover on it. Initially the color of triangle is red, then it changes to  `#9f1212`, then to `#2a60f4` and finally it changes to yellow. After completing animation the triangle color changes to red. 
color changing order:

```
red - #9f1212 - #2a60f4 - yellow - red
```

In the above order after yellow I want to repeat the color order in reverse i.e. after yellow change to `#2a60f4`  and then to  `#9f1212` and finally it becomes red.

Expected output order:

```
red - #9f1212 - #2a60f4 - yellow -#2a60f4 - #9f1212- red
```

code:

```css
.triangle-up {
 width: 0;
 height: 0;
 border-left: 55px solid transparent;
 border-right: 55px solid transparent;
 border-bottom: 90px solid red;
}
.triangle-up:hover{
 border-bottom: 90px solid #fd7a7a;
    border-left: 55px solid transparent;
 border-right: 55px solid transparent;
      animation-name: example;
  animation-duration:4s;
}
@keyframes example {
 0% {
 border-bottom: 90px solid #9f1212;
  }
  50% {
 border-bottom: 90px solid #2a60f4;
  }
    100% {
 border-bottom: 90px solid yellow;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="triangle-up"></div>
```

How can I get the expected output? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You can take some idea from here [CSS-Tricks](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/t/transition/).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're almost there. Add these two:

- [`animation-duration`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/animation-direction) with a value of `alternate` to cycle the animation forth and back
- [`animation-iteration-count`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/animation-iteration-count) with a value of `infinite` to repeat the animation indefinitely

See the updated snippet:

```css
.triangle-up {
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-left: 55px solid transparent;
    border-right: 55px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 90px solid red;
}
.triangle-up:hover{
    border-bottom: 90px solid #fd7a7a;
    border-left: 55px solid transparent;
    border-right: 55px solid transparent;
    animation-name: example;
    animation-duration:4s;
    animation-direction: alternate;
    animation-iteration-count: infinite;
}
@keyframes example {
    0% {
        border-bottom: 90px solid #9f1212;
    }
    50% {
        border-bottom: 90px solid #2a60f4;
    }
    100% {
        border-bottom: 90px solid yellow;
    }
}
```

```html
<div class="triangle-up"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want the animation to be seamless, with no jumping to colors, simply extend the animation duration and add in the steps to your animation. If you want the animation to loop add `animation-iteration-count: infinite;`

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/z057g6ju/1/)

```css
.triangle-up {
 width: 0;
 height: 0;
 border-left: 55px solid transparent;
 border-right: 55px solid transparent;
 border-bottom: 90px solid red;
}
.triangle-up:hover{
 border-bottom: 90px solid #fd7a7a;
  border-left: 55px solid transparent;
 border-right: 55px solid transparent;
  animation-name: example;
  animation-duration:10s;
}
@keyframes example {
  0% {
 border-bottom: 90px solid red;
  }
  16.66% {
 border-bottom: 90px solid #9f1212;
  }
  33.33% {
 border-bottom: 90px solid #2a60f4;
  }
  50% {
 border-bottom: 90px solid yellow;
  }
  66.66% {
  border-bottom: 90px solid #2a60f4;
 
  }
  83.33% {
 border-bottom: 90px solid #9f1212;
  }
  100% {
 border-bottom: 90px solid red;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="triangle-up"></div>
```